# Select / Drag or by rectangle CMV Application

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, select, configurable-map-viewer

Anyone able to suggest to this noob if there is a way to change the selection option in my CMV application from individual polygons (one at a time) to an option of selecting multiple polygons at once and having attributes display in the attribute table widget, in this case "parcels", by a shape of rectangle. I've notice documentation online also references it as "Select / Drag". I can't seem to find any documentation on how i would write or change the existing cmv script. I've looked at other JavaScript api maps that have this method of selection and cannot figure out how to implement this into mine.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly, this funnctionality already exists in my [Search widget](https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets#search) which is a companion to my [Attributes Tables widget](https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets#attributes-tables).

Comment: Tim... This is what I'm looking for ... http://webmap.jws.com/taxmap/viewer.aspx?JWSCONFIG=MS_PearlRiverCounty Horrible map but the "Identify" button shows "Single Click to select a parcel""Drag a rectangle to select multiple parcels"Is there a way to incorporate this as the default way of selecting without adding a widget?

Comment: The functionality of that Identify is pretty much identical as the Search widget using point and rectangle. You can certainly modify the Search widget to constrict the options to just the one you desire. CMV is built to be extended via widgets so you may not get very far without adding a widget or modifying an existing one.